# Перегрузка операторов << и >> для базового класса и класса наследника

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, перегрузка-операторов

```
Base* b = new Derived();
```

`Base` - наследник `Derived()`. Если у обоих этих классов есть функция `print()`, и мы заходим ее вызвать от `*b`, то вызовется функция определенная для `Base`, хотя мне нужна функция класса наследника. Я знаю, что такое можно починить сделав `print()` в `Base` виртуальной и написав `override` у функции наследника, однако если я собираюсь перегрузить `operator<<` для обоих классов, то этот способ использовать не получится, какие есть варианты справится с этой проблемой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, ваш оператор `<<` вполне может вызывать виртуальную функцию `print`, правда? :)

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void print(ostream&os) const { os << "Base\n"; }
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    void print(ostream&os) const override { os << "Derived\n"; }
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Base& b)
{
    b.print(os);
    return os;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Base* a = new Base();
    Base* b = new Derived();

    Base c;
    Derived d;

    cout << *a << *b;
    cout << c << d;
}
```